# Import vector data from PostGIS to an R session

Tags: postgis, r, vector

So now I know that it has been asked before many times but I wanted to know what are the main problems that one encounters when using rgdal. To be more specific I have 2 lines of code:

```
dcV="PG:dname='remote' host=localhost user='postgres' password='pass' port=5432 scehma='public' table='vector2' mode=2"
poly=readOGR(dcV)
```

but I have I get an error that says:

> Error in ogrListLayers(dsn = dsn) : Cannot open data source

and I have no idea what is causing it because I loaded a raster layer the same way but instead of "vector2" I wrote "raster2".And yes both of them exist and can be fetched from QGIS
P.S I am working with Linux and I am calling the Rscript from the terminal

EDIT:
When I typed `drv = ogrDrivers();drv[grepl("PostGIS",drv$long_name),]` I got the following output:

[image]

Comment: What's the state of your postGIS driver in rgdal? Run `drv = ogrDrivers();drv[grepl("PostGIS",drv$long_name),]` and add the output to your Q. Also, what was "raster2"? A PostGIS Raster? What sort of R object did you get back? With readOGR? Or SpatialPixelsDataFrame? Include that and the output in your Q too for completeness.

Comment: @Spacedman Yeah, I used raster2psql to input that in my database and actually got back my raster. I can upload the syntax of that if you want, but the point is that I can't fetch the vector data using readOGR and now the output (from the line that you provided) is this:
         name          long_name write  copy isVector
58 PostgreSQL PostgreSQL/PostGIS  TRUE FALSE     TRUE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah so the solution was pretty simple, the only thing I had to change was

```
dcV="PG:dname='remote' host=localhost user='postgres' password='pass' port=5432 scehma='public' table='vector2' mode=2"
```

to

```
dcV="PG:dname='remote' host=localhost user='postgres' password='pass' port=5432
```

and then I added 1 line and 1 parameter. Where the line was:`ogrListLayers(dcV)` so I can see what was the name of my layer and to check if my PostGIS was on.

Now the parameter was in this line: `poly=readOGR(dcV)` where I changed it to `poly=readOGR(dsn=dcV, layer="vector2")` adding the name of my vector

P.S I you want to add a raster layer to your PostGIS database, the general command for Linux using the pipe method is:

```
raster2pgsql -I -C -s <SPATIAL_REF_ID> <PATH_TO_RASTER FILE> <SCHEMA>.<DBTABLE> |psql -h <h as in host> -U <U as in username> -p <p as in port> -d <d as in database>
```

Comment: I just noticed your typo for "schema":  `scehma='public'` - was that also killing it?

Comment: No, that was my mistake as I was typing it here